# Automated deployment (Wordmove for EE)

Tags: mysql, ee, sql

I've been trying to figure out a way for executing automated deployment of EE sites via Capistrano or similar.

I've come across various tutorials but all require Git on the server, and most don't include DB migration.

I was wondering if there is a similar tool to [Wordmove](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove) out there for EE? I really like that it uses rsync and sql commands for the migration so no special software is needed on the server side, only SSH access.

I know this has already been asked a million times, but figured with EE3 out now, and given the age of some of the questions, I thought it might be worth rehashing.

Comment: Does [it](http://medoingthings.com/writing/2015/03/front-end-deployment-for-the-rest-of-us) helps? I couldn't try it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with Capistrano and building various one-off bash scripts for deployment I decided to build my own move tools.

Drum-roll..... Introducing **eemove**! Automated deployment for ExpressionEngine sites: https://github.com/sparkison/eemove

Currently in an alpha state so likely to be bugs. Can grab the generated/executable jar file using the release tab of the repo.

All comments, suggestions, etc. welcome!